# Changing the Language that is processed

Tags: filepicker.io

I created a tutorial for the Aviary with Filepicker.io, now one of the users at my tutorial site want to know how to change the language as he is from a whole different country. My problem is I try to access the iframe though we can't because it is not the same origin. Anyone have any suggestions as how to change the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ink Filepicker doesn't currently support internationalization. It's a highly requested feature.

Comment: Thanks Liyan Chang, yes I'm sure it is, they should give us an optional parameter for the instantiation code for `lang: { },`

Comment: That sounds like a good interface; I think that having all the internationalized strings and having the code handle that and all the edge cases is the blocker.

Comment: Yes you are write, though the strings wouldn't need to be performed instead id names/classes/ however they classify them at then the user can simply typed what they want in that order. Of course `lang:'en',` would be easier we could also do `lang:{computer:'My Computer',cancel:'Cancel',etc },`

Comment: Update. Filepicker currently support internationalization. More details: https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/support/general/29

Answer (score 0):

Why not inject into the iframe after page load by locating the  using jquery?

Comment: You can't inject to it, I tried it and it says, `Page requesting access has protocol of http://, page trying to be access has a protocol of https://`